# Add tab under android.app.fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I want to add tabs inside android.app.fragment and not to be in action bar
All solutions on the web are talking about tabs inside an activity, tabs in the action bar, tabs inside android.support.v4.app.Fragment this is available in my case.

Thank you

Comment: Having tabs within ActionBar is natural practice in Android. What exactly do you want to achieve by adding it do android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

Comment: I want to add the tab as an view inside the fragment not within the action bar but under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution. I think it's suitable and satisfy my requirements.
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip
but i have a problem in using it, I will open new thread for that.

thanks all for trying

Comment: It seems that this lib uses android.support.v4.app.Fragment ... Do you remember if you found a final solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check here : [tab example](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)

Here u have fully implemented example , which u can adapt to your needs.

Enjoy,